# VB6 execution with database is different when stepping through vs running

Tags: debugging, ms-access, vb6

I've come across a weird scenario with the following code in a vb6 app:

```
Private database As dao.Database
Set database = openDaoDatabase([some valid database location], False)

createDBField database, "Table", "FirstRow", dao.dbInteger, 0, "0"

Public Sub createDBField(targetDB As dao.Database, strTable As String, strField As String, dbType As dao.DataTypeEnum, Size As Integer, strDefValue As String)
   Dim td  As dao.TableDef
   Dim fld As dao.field

   Set td = targetDB.TableDefs(strTable)
   Set fld = td.CreateField(strField, dbType, 0)
   If dbType = dao.DataTypeEnum.dbText Or dbType = dao.DataTypeEnum.dbMemo Then fld.AllowZeroLength = True
   If strDefValue <> "" Then fld.DefaultValue = strDefValue
   td.Fields.Append fld
   Set td = Nothing
   Set fld = Nothing
End Sub
```

When I step through, everything works and the new field is added to the database.  However, when I simply run the application, the database becomes corrupted due to 'inconsistency'.  I added some error handling and now get the error: "Unrecognized database format: [path]".
After searching the Microsoft database, I found a solution: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238401.  I'm using the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider, have SP6 installed and have a reference to the Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library, but it's still not working!

Any thoughts?

Update:
td.Fields.Append fld is the culprit.  After removing all silent error handling, I was able to catch an error: "Run-time error 3343 Unrecognized Database Format".  For some reason, I can just step over it though.

Comment: "On Error Resume Next" is poison. Take it out and you'll find what's really failing. Honestly, there are "no good reasons" to use it in VBA.

Comment: Very few good reasons - and it needs to be disabled fairly promptly - however in this case yes, absolutely!

Comment: @Binary Worrier - I realize that the On Resume Next is dangerous and have removed it. I can thankfully say that I did not write this function.  On Error Resume Next is everywhere in this program and it's given me more than my share of headaches.

Comment: What values are being passed into the subroutine that cause the problem?   More specfically strField, dbType, Size and strDefValue.  I have somewhat similar logic I've been using for years in Access without any such problems.

Comment: How exactly are you using the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider?

Comment: Neither here nor there, but why in the world would you want AllowZLS set to TRUE??? I hate A2003 because it defaults to it and I have to turn it off. I certainly don't want to have to check for both Is Null and <>"" when looking for empty fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem is happening because of the `AllowZeroLength` property.   I suspect the field should be added to the fields collection and the `AllowZeroLength` property updated.

After

```
td.Fields.Append fld
```

put something like the following:

```
Set tdfField = tabledef.Fields(strField)
Set prp = tdfField.CreateProperty("AllowZeroLength", dbboolean, True)
tdfField.Properties.Append prp
```

Note the above is aircode and not tested.

That said, it doesn't make a lot of sense to me for a text or `MEMO` field's `AllowZeroLength` property to default to `True`.  After all, the front end user can't really visually distinguish between the `NULL` value and a zero length string value.

Comment: I must say, I'm shocked, but that worked! Thanks so much, Tony!

Comment: I should read all the posts before making comments (see above)! I hate the A2003 default to AllowZLS=True with a purple passion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a call to database.close that might be the cause.  If your VB app terminates abruptly that might leave the DB in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 0):

Which line is the error occurring on?  Usually when I run into VB errors like this they are timing related.  Stepping through gives enough time for something to finish processing.  Try adding some sleep commands before the statement that is causing the error.